# Checking if a sum of expressions is smaller than its upper bound?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Let \begin{equation} A+B+C+D \leq \frac{\Lambda}{\mu},\end{equation}
be always true.

Now, define the following:

```
  a = (\[Psi] Exp[(-\[Mu] \[Tau]2)])/(\[Psi] + Subscript[\[Alpha], 
     2] + \[Mu]);
h1 = \[Mu] + Subscript[c, 1] - a Subscript[c, 1];
h2 = \[Mu] + Subscript[c, 2] - a Subscript[c, 2];
h3 = \[Mu] + \[Xi] (1 - Exp[(-\[Mu] \[Tau]1)]) + Subscript[c, 3] + 
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] - a Subscript[c, 3];
b1 = 1 + ((h2 \[CurlyPhi])/(h1 (\[Theta] + Subscript[c, 
         2] + \[Mu]) ));
   AngleA = FullSimplify[\[CapitalLambda]/(b1 h1)];
    AngleB = 
  FullSimplify[\[CurlyPhi]/(\[Theta] + Subscript[c, 
       2] + \[Mu]) (AngleS)];
    AngleD = 
  FullSimplify[(Subscript[c, 
       1]/(\[Psi] + Subscript[\[Alpha], 
         2] + \[Mu])) (AngleS) + (Subscript[c, 
       2]/(\[Psi] + Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + \[Mu])) (AngleV)];
```

Set $C=0$, So we wish to check if:

1. `AngleA`+`AngleB`+`AngleD` $\leq \frac{\Lambda}{\mu}$
2. `AngleA`+`AngleB`+`AngleD` $\leq 3\frac{\Lambda}{\mu}$

where all parameters are strictly positive and variables $A, B, C, D$ are non-negative.

I tried:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
varn = {\[CapitalLambda], \[Mu], \[Beta], \[CurlyPhi], Subscript[c, 
   1], Subscript[c, 2], Subscript[c, 3], \[Theta], Subscript[\[Alpha],
    1], Subscript[\[Alpha], 2], \[Xi], \[Psi], \[Tau]1, \[Tau]2};
Assuming[
 Element[varn, 
  PositiveReals], (
   e^(\[Mu] \[Tau]2) \[CapitalLambda] (Subscript[c, 
       1] (\[Theta] + \[Mu] + Subscript[c, 
         2]) + (\[Theta] + \[Mu] + \[CurlyPhi]) (\[Mu] + \[Psi] + 
         Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]) + 
      Subscript[c, 
       2] (\[Mu] + \[CurlyPhi] + \[Psi] + Subscript[\[Alpha], 
         2])))/(-\[CurlyPhi] \[Psi] Subscript[c, 
     2] - \[Psi] Subscript[c, 
     1] (\[Theta] + \[Mu] + Subscript[c, 2]) + 
    e^(\[Mu] \[Tau]2) (\[Mu] (\[Theta] + \[Mu] + \[CurlyPhi]) + \
(\[Mu] + \[CurlyPhi]) Subscript[c, 2] + 
       Subscript[c, 
        1] (\[Theta] + \[Mu] + Subscript[c, 2])) (\[Mu] + \[Psi] + 
       Subscript[\[Alpha], 2])) <= \[CapitalLambda]/\[Mu] // 
  FullSimplify]
```

where the expression in the inequality is from `FullSimplify[AngleA + AngleB + AngleD]`.

Comment: Putting Clear["Global`*"] in the second block of code erases the first block. `e` is not included in `varn`. Is it a variable or is it intended to be the number `E`

Comment: @BobHanlon I summed `AngleA`, `AngleB` and `AngleD` then did the second computation. It is the number `E`

Comment: @BobHanlon Did you get any answer?

Comment: No, I didn't. Recommend that you correct the question by replacing all occurrences of `e` with `E`. You should not require people to read the comments to get the correct expressions/code.

Comment: @BobHanlon doesn’t mathematica realise ‘e’ as exponent?

Comment: No, `e` is interpreted as a user-defined variable. If you mean `2.71828...` you must use either `E` or `Exp[_]`. Before copy and paste into this forum, code should be in `InputForm` so that `E` comes in as `E` and not `e`. Then when copied and pasted back into Mma, it will be correct.

Comment: @BobHanlon I have adjusted the question. Please tell me if I need to change anything else.